# Writing to a serial device failing mysteriously

Tags: data, input-devices

I have a device which communicates with the computer through serial. The device waits until it receives the character 'a', and then begins to stream data. I have been able to connect to the device and test it in PuTTY, where hitting 'a' will begin the stream and I can read the data just fine in terminal.

Now I would like to work with this data in Mathematica. Working in a notebook, it looks like I can properly open the device. However, attempting to write to it gives me a rather cryptic error--especially when I know this works in PuTTY.

[image: This is the strange error I get.]

If anyone can help me to make sense of this, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, from the syntax, that you are on a Windows PC.

I can't remember where I saw this, but i had similar issue with my Arduino and resolved it by referring to the port in the following manner:

```
    dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "\\.\\COM11"];
    DeviceWrite[dev, 1];
    (* Code to read the data stream... *)
    DeviceClose[dev];
```

Please note the whacky syntax for defining the COM port. That's only for windows. The Mac's will use the Unix syntax like in this [example](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/connected-device-framework/build-an-arduino-powered-smart-doorbell.html).